# javascript open modal when leave content and enter it again

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have a litte problem with javascript and a bootstrap modal.

I want to display a modal, when the user leaves the website with the mouse and re-enters.

The if else condition does not work. What I'm doing wrong?

```
<script>

var out=0;

if(out==1){
   $("#page").one("mouseover", function () {
     window.setTimeout(function () {
         $('#myModal').modal({show: true});
     }, 3000)
    }).on("mouseover", function () {
     return false;
    });

}

document.addEventListener("mouseover", myFunction);
document.addEventListener("mouseout", mySecondFunction);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("page").innerHTML += "Moused over!<br>"
}
function mySecondFunction() {
    document.getElementById("page").innerHTML += "Moused out!<br>"
    out=1;
}

</script>
```

[here is a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vvs7sai9AxG5aZhYYj9T?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseEnter et mouseLeave events instead of mouseover and mouseout.

What about this code ?

```
document.addEventListener("mouseenter", myFunction);
document.addEventListener("mouseleave", mySecondFunction);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("page").innerHTML += "Moused over!<br>";
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
function mySecondFunction() {
    document.getElementById("page").innerHTML += "Moused out!<br>";
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp

Comment: Here is a website with this function: http://www.hotelrosatsch.ch/

When the user leave the website with the mouse and re-enter then shows a modal after 10seconds but how can i do this? I have the outermost container with id page but when i hover another container in this "page" container with the mouse, I get the message moused out!

Comment: The mouseEnter event will be fired only if the mouse ENTER in your site. 

If you want to wait before show your modal use setTimeout();

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support!

I have found a solution:

```
<script>

var n = 0;
$( "div.enterleave" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $( "p:first", this ).text( "mouse enter" );
    if(n==1){
      window.setTimeout(function () {
              $('#myModal').modal('show');
          }, 10000)
    }

  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    n++;
    $( "p:first", this ).text( "leavecount" + n );

  });
</script>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wv2X8GTPaNifI4Sr9X84?p=preview)